# Metabuild tool to handle multiple cross-builds simultaneously

Tags: c++, build, cross-build

I have a mid-sized C++ project that runs on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X, both 32- and 64-bit. On some platforms it has more than one variant (e.g. Gtk-2 and Gtk-3 variants on Linux). Being mostly a hobby programmer, I don't have resources for dedicated build machines for each platform. So I installed cross-compilers for each one so that all building takes place on my Linux box.

I want to be able to build all ten or so variants with a single command. Right now I achieve this with a quick and dirty Python script that creates a makefile (actually I switched to ninja recently but it's not very relevant I guess). It creates Windows installers, Debian packages and whatnot for each variant. But I want a cleaner solution because my script is not gonna scale well as the project grows.

So my question is: **What metabuild tools are able to create a single Makefile (or similar, like a ninja build file) that can handle multiple toolkits (cross-compilers) and custom commands (to create installers etc.)?**

I tried CMake (and some others) but it's not obvious to me how to work with multiple toolkits. Most tools seem to create one Makefile per configuration.

**Edit:** Now, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556122/906444) answer claims that it's not possible. I don't understand why. If I can do it with my 15 minutes python script, I feel like there must be a tool able to do it for me.

Comment: You make me think about it, yet I've never needed a tool like this and I'm doing some search right now. Sharing my thoughts, maybe the fact that making a script take only 15 minutes is the reason for the lack of this kind of tool. I think that the preparation of something that works with everything, would take so much time as you need to do it with a single script. 
One that might be interesting: http://bakefile.org/

Comment: Cmake is the way to go here I'm affraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this behaviour with CMake, using [Toolchains](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) and [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html). Different makefiles will still be created behind the scenes, but that doesn't affect the user or the scalability of the project.

First, you will need to turn your project into a CMake project, with all the ifs and elses needed to build on all the different platforms in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

You can create a set of toolchain files e.g. named `<target>.toolchain` and your cross build `CMakeLists.txt` where all the magic is done:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(cross-build-project)
include(ExternalProject)

set(project_dir <path to your CMake project>)
set(targets_dir ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/targets)

function(add_target target_toolchain)
  get_filename_component(target_name ${target_toolchain} NAME_WE)
  ExternalProject_Add(
      ${target_name}
      PREFIX ${targets_dir}/${target_name}
      SOURCE_DIR ${project_dir}
      CMAKE_ARGS -DTOOLCHAIN_FILE=${target_toolchain}
      BINARY_DIR ${targets_dir}/${target_name}
    )
endfunction(add_target)

file(GLOB toolchains "*.toolchain")
foreach(toolchain ${toolchains})
  add_target(${toolchain})
endforeach()
```

This should provide a platform that can be adjusted to your specific needs and scale well with the project.